# Fuzzy join with R produces duplicate columns and no joined values

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm adapting the example [shown here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881/2), where I'd like to left-join some test results to existing session data, but I know that the tests may have been conducted three hours before or after the session was created, by the same user.

However, I am getting duplicate `user_id` columns as a result, despite specifying them in the `by` option, and the values themselves are not added to the data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
library(fuzzyjoin)

sessions = tribble(
  ~user_id, ~session_id, ~session_created_at,
  1, 1, "2019-01-01T15:30:00",
  1, 2, "2019-01-02T00:00:30",
  1, 3, "2019-01-04T12:30:00"
) %>%
  mutate_at("session_created_at", as_datetime)

tests = tribble(
  ~user_id, ~test_id, ~test_created_at, ~test_value,
  1, 7, "2019-01-01T15:28:00", "foo",
  1, 8, "2019-01-01T23:59:30", "bar"
) %>%
  mutate_at("test_created_at", as_datetime) %>% 
  mutate(
    start = test_created_at + hours(3),
    end = test_created_at - hours(3)
  )

sessions %>% 
  fuzzy_left_join(
    tests,
    by = c(
      "user_id" = "user_id",
      "session_created_at" = "start",
      "session_created_at" = "end"
    ),
    match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`)
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 9
#>   user_id.x session_id session_created_at  user_id.y test_id
#>       <dbl>      <dbl> <dttm>                  <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1         1          1 2019-01-01 15:30:00        NA      NA
#> 2         1          2 2019-01-02 00:00:30        NA      NA
#> 3         1          3 2019-01-04 12:30:00        NA      NA
#> # … with 4 more variables: test_created_at <dttm>, test_value <chr>,
#> #   start <dttm>, end <dttm>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Why is that, and what do I have to do to get it working?

I should add that when I run:

```r
sessions %>% 
  left_join(tests, by = c("user_id" = "user_id"))
```

I get the proper columns, but of course not the correct test results joined. And when I run this, I get my expected results, but it seems inefficient:

```r
sessions %>% 
  left_join(tests) %>% 
  filter(test_created_at - hours(3) <= session_created_at) %>% 
  filter(test_created_at + hours(3) >= session_created_at)
```

Comment: Your last chunk of code that joins & then filters is exactly what I was going to suggest.  You're right it's not super efficient, but as long as the data isn't huge it should be ok.  Alternatively, you could use SQL inequality joins with the `sqldf` package.

Comment: Unfortunately the data is huge and that particular join gives me an out of memory error. I'm not sure if `fuzzyjoin` will be any more memory efficient, but I'd like to at least get the example running because I don't understand what's going on. Maybe I'll also file a bug report.

Comment: Posted a bug report here: https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin/issues/55

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned that this is [per design](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin/issues/55#issuecomment-501286643):

> […] the design assumption is that during a fuzzy join it's useful to keep both sides of the join to be able to understand how it matched and there's no specific logic to handle collapsing them for equality.

Until such deduplication logic is implemented, all you can do is go ahead and remove all columns that you know are duplicates, e.g. by `select(-ends_with(".y"))` and renaming the ones ending with `.x` to lose their suffix.